# Директивы компилятора для xaml, wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Расскажите пожалуйста, можно ли добиться возможности использования директив компилятора в `xaml`, `wpf`. Если можно, то как?

Например, (не буквально, но как-то так):

```
<Grid>
#if DEBUG
            <TextBlock Text="Debug mode!!" />
#else
            <TextBlock Text="Release mode here!" />
#endif
</Grid>
```

Comment: Вот что сходу гуглится: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19940157/6766879 Смотрели?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я смотрел, но подумал, что кому-то еще будет интересно как бы быть ознакомленным. Будем считать, что не смотрел. Не то чтобы это очень важно знать (про директивы xaml), конечно....  Получается, что такой вопрос не на пользу задавать?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Это как бы [экспериментальный вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9409/%d0%9d%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-soru-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be).

Comment: @АндрейNOP, [вот еще](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9408/185885)

Comment: Если вы знаете/нашли ответ, то наверно его стоит написать, верно? Сейчас же вы просите помощи, когда она вам не нужна. А это уже не очень хорошо по отношению к другим участникам, ибо они заходят сюда, тратят свое время на вникание, гугление (за вас). Мне допустим пришло уведомление о новом вопросе. Но зачем мне на него давать ответ, если это можете без труда сделать вы? Ради репутации? Ну, я за ней не гонюсь, Ради "пополнения базы ruSO? Ну, это ваша инициатива. Ради помощи человеку я бы может дал ответ (причем тот, что выдает гугл по первой же ссылке).

Comment: Ну ОК, мне кажется, в таких случаях лучше сразу писать самоответ. Если кому есть что добавить — существующий ответ его не остановит. А то что сейчас: я захожу в топик, думаю что ТС нужна помощь, но у меня нет времени запускать студию и проверять что-то самому прямо сейчас. Я кидаю ссылку в комментарии, вдруг у ТС работа стоит, ему ссылки будет достаточно чтобы начать что-то делать.